# Geo Points GET Limit

Tags: elasticsearch, geopoints

Using Elasticsearch 5.2, I stored around 20k Geo Points.

I want to query all of them to show them in a Google map. However, as specified in the documentation, the limit size seems to be 10k (I get the error `Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [20000]`.

Is there a workaround to get all my points ?

The query I used is :

```
{
    "size":10000,
    "_source": ["geo"],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must" : [
                { "term" : { myId" : 1234 } },
                {
                    "range" :{
                        "@timestamp" : {
                            "gte" : "now-10m"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try the [scroll and scan api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html)? This will give you all the results, but not in a single query.

Comment: I didn't know about this scroll api. I'll give a look, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a large result set you can use the [scroll and scan](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) api

It can be done in two steps.

First- To you search query add a scroll

```
POST /index_name/type_name/_search?scroll=1m
{
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

This will return a scroll id. Using the scroll id you can call the following repeatedly to get 100(size) results every time.

```
POST  /_search/scroll 
{
    "scroll" : "1m", 
    "scroll_id" : "DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAAAAD4WYm9laVYtZndUQlNsdDcwakFMNjU1QQ==" 
}
```